# Regarding UPDATE query. why my approach updates all the records with the same data?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-update, multiple-tables

this my approach its working but it updates all the tables with same data. when you update row 1 it will update the all rows.

```
          <?php
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM famcomp WHERE app_id='".$_GET["app_id"]."'");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
  ?>
            <td><input type="text" name="app_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fullname[]" value="<?php echo $row['fullname']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fage[]" value="<?php echo $row['fage']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="frel[]" value="<?php echo $row['frel']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fcivil[]" value="<?php echo $row['fcivil']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fedu[]" value="<?php echo $row['fedu']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="foccup[]" value="<?php echo $row['foccup']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="finco[]" value="<?php echo $row['finco']; ?>" class="input" /></td>
        </tr>    
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

here's my approach:$N is to count the total row of fullname then use it in for loop and also when I echo my UPDATES it does give the right details. but when I query it updates all the row with the same data.

```
$N = count($_POST['fullname']);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE famcomp set fullname='" . $_POST["fullname"][$i] . "', fage='" . $_POST["fage"][$i] . "', frel='" . $_POST["frel"][$i] . "', fcivil='" . $_POST["fcivil"][$i] . "', fedu='" . $_POST["fedu"][$i] . "', foccup='" . $_POST["foccup"][$i] . "', finco='" . $_POST["finco"][$i] . "' WHERE app_id='" . $_POST["app_id"][$i] . "'");
```

Comment: add the echo of your updates, the table ddl, sample data with that particular id, and what you expect afterwards ( with respect to the original sample data )

Comment: okay sir check the updates.

Comment: You have *n* number of rows with *app_id*, but don't include an *id* or other unique value, so of course it will update all the rows with the same values

Comment: please edit the question to include that update ( and remove the answer )

Comment: @Sean good point there I will try to include app_id and id thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Solution to the approach:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE famcomp set app_id ='". $_POST['app_id'][$i]. "', fullname='" . $_POST["fullname"][$i] . "', fage='" . $_POST["fage"][$i] . "', frel='" . $_POST["frel"][$i] . "', fcivil='" . $_POST["fcivil"][$i] . "', fedu='" . $_POST["fedu"][$i] . "', foccup='" . $_POST["foccup"][$i] . "', finco='" . $_POST["finco"][$i] . "' WHERE id ='" . $_POST["id"][$i] . "'");
```

Comment: Don't put your edits as an answer unless it is an answer. Click on the edit link - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32152153/edit - and edit the question directly

Comment: **Never** concatenate variables verbatim into a MySQL statement. You're asking for SQL injection.